# External Monitor Shows "Input Not supported"

Tags: display, external-display

When I turn on my laptop, I am guessing it works but monitor doesn't. Monitor goes blank/pink screen; Nothing shows at all. So, I thought lets try with external monitor. External LCD monitor shows "Input not supported"

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds a lot like a graphics card issue. Does it display anything during boot-up?

Comment: Is the screen blank or pink? What OS are you using? What hardware? Is the external monitor VGA, HDMI, DVI or what? Can you hear the laptop's fans or HDD working?

Comment: I can hear the fan and HDD working. Trying with VGA to external monitor. Doesn't display anything during boot up and even after. I would say blank rather pink. Windows XP.Thanks..

Comment: does your laptop have a function button to enable the external monitor? usually its Funct + F8, but look for the function key with a rectangle that looks vaguely like a monitor. if you hit it, does your problem go away?

Comment: Boot into safe mode, this should force the output to display in a low resolution supported by any monitor. If you still don't get a display on an external monitor then your graphics chip is likely to be duff

Comment: Laptop does have function key and for external monitor it is Funct+F4. When I pressed these, external monitor shows "Input not supported"

Comment: I will try the "Safe Mode" option.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the laptop still runs XP, which is now unsupported and has been for a while, means it's very old.

Given the symptoms you describe and the age of the machine, a hardware failure is near certain. Get a new machine, it's much cheaper than repairing the old one. If you still need your data, remove the drive (you may need to buy the appropriate screwdrivers for $5) and buy or borrow a USB adapter ($10-20) to read from it.